# Require and module statements not recognized in PyCharm

Tags: node.js, pycharm

I do most of my work in python but we also have a node.js project that I work on so I was pleased to find that PyCharm supported the Node.js plugin.

After I installed it I was still having significant troubles getting a lot of the core node.js libraries and statements to be recognized by PyCharm. Most notably, PyCharm doesn't recognize the require or module statements.

Any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer! In the Javascript tab of your project settings open the Library subtab. In there make sure you have the Node.js Core Modules and Node.js Globals checked as shown [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/01/getting-started-with-node-js-in-webstorm/).